# Umbraco: Create Model Object for a Node Using ModelsBuilder?

Tags: model, content-management-system, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 7.5 and ModelsBuilder in "AppData" mode, I have a Settings document type and content node, which of course doesn't have a view (template).

In a global code file, I create an instance of settings node like this:

```
IPublishedContent Settings = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(123);
```

Now, how can I create an initialize the model that is created by ModelsBuilder? Although I can make calls to `Settings.GetPropertyValue(...)`, I want to initialize and use the "SiteSettings.generated.cs" strongly typed model that is generated by ModelsBuilder for me, which already contains the properties I have defined.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the answer:

The models generated by ModelsBuilder all inherit from **PublishedContentModel**, which has a constructor that receives an **IPublishContent** object as input and instantiate the model object for you. So, the code would be (SiteSettings is the name of the model class):

```
IPublishedContent settingsNode = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(123);
var settingsModel = new SiteSettings(settingsNode);
```

Comment: Tread carefully when creating new instances of UmbracoHelper - it has quite an overhead and creating too many instances can kill your site's performance.